# Create a native C++-Object within WCF Service Application

Tags: c#, wcf

My intention is, to run a Web service which accesses C++ native functions. Therefore I created a WCF Service Application (which contains contract and implementation) which references a C++/ CLI Wrapper around my Native C++ code. I did the following steps (following 2b from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorman/archive/2007/08/31/loading-c-assemblies-in-asp-net.aspx)

1. The native C++ API is exported.
2. native C++ dll's are loaded with "delayed loaded"
3. I set a path for native dll and its 3rd  party dll's in the Web.config
4. defined asp-compatibility in the web.config file
5. Defined a Global.asax File for accessing the loading path for native dll's

I can run the service as long as I don't create the wrapper-object, which creates the native C++ object in the constructor.The problem is the creation of the native C++ object. If I test it with the WCFTestClient I get the unspecific errors:

Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible.

My question is: Is something wrong in this concept? I can use this wrapper and the native C++ object if I call it from a C#-Project. Do I have to choose another project type than a WCF Service Application?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I found the error in the web.config - File!

Answer (score 0):

The concept is right, and it should work fine. I think when the service try to create the native C++ object, an error/exception happens, and which crashes the service. I suggest you write a small C# test program, which calls the C++/CLI DLL to create the native C++, if this small programs works fine, then move the code to your service.

Or you can debug the service, find the actual error, that would help too.